# starts-with() not working in IE8

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to identify a button using the below xpath, on IE8 this is not working while on Firefox this is working fine.

```
 //input[starts-with(@src,'/images/btn_signin.gif')]
```

the full attribute for this element is

`/images/btn_signin.gif?osCsid=468e46e5277f56b3ead78619ec7c43a7?`

Could anyone let me know whats wrong with IE8?

How can this is to be done with IE?

Answer (score 2):

Try with below cssSelector

```
By.cssSelector("input[src^='/images/btn_signin.gif']")
or
By.cssSelector("input[src*='images'][src*='btn_signin.gif']")
```

You can replace xpath with cssSelector in possible cases so that it works fine in all browsers. Refer [this post](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/03/replace-xpath-with-css-selector.html)

Comment: my element attribute is "/images/btn_signin.gif?osCsid=468e46e5277f56b3ead78619ec7c43a7?  the sid will be changed everytime. so this will not help... that

Comment: above locator locate elements @src started with '/images/btn_signin.gif' but not consider sid part. so it should work same like startw-with(@src,'/images/btn_signin.gif') in xpath.

Comment: Is it throwing any exception ? I've added another cssSelector. try with that.

Comment: the last one worked..but I am still wondering why these not working? we have supplied the xpath correctly.. any clue for this.?  could you also explain the cssSelector that worked.

Comment: There is no native support for xpath in IE, so we can not say all the xpaths will work in IE same as other browsers(firefox). https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/XpathInWebDriver

Comment: Refer below post to know more about cssSelectors http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/03/replace-xpath-with-css-selector.html